# prevent all bots from accessing a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, bots

In asp.net, c# web applciation, is it possible to prevent bots from accessing a particular page?

I want to prevent all bots from accessing the payment page on my site.

Comment: What kind of bots? What are you afraid of?

Comment: all bots - I don't need the page to be indexed by search engines, so can block all bots from this single page.

Comment: Nothing can stop terminators.  Nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

You can **request** that the bots don't visit your site (see Projapati's answer for more details on how to do that), or certain directories, or certain files; but it's really just a request.  As long as 'Joe Schmoe User' can open a browser and see the page; nothing prevents someone from automating that visit.

You could try to do something where you block certain IPs that you know are used by various bots/crawlers; but it'd be a losing proposition.  You could never say, with any certainty, that it wasn't a bot visiting the page.

Or you could modify the site so that only authenticated users can access that particular page and hope that nobody goes through the trouble of setting up a fake account to use.

Answer (score 4):

You may need the robot.txt file in place.
Here you can find more info on how to use it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Answer (score 0):

Place a file called `robots.txt` in the root folder of your website and add the following code to it

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /paymentpage.php # change this to your payment page.
```

You can also disallow a particular bot, Google for example:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /paymentpage.php # change this to your payment page.
```

Learn more about robots.txt:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/robots.shtml